Error encountering building react-native app using expo

I had a "Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-splash-screen:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar." this issue when i build native app using expo esa. Any one know solution for this.
I'm building a react native app.I need to find the solution for this. (From online sources this is due to older packages.)Is there any in my dependencies?
